# How can a 32-bit and 64-bit app share an HKLM registry setting?

Tags: registry, wow64

We have an Office .NET Add-In and the Add-In runs in the bitness of Office. So 32-bit Office on 64-bit Windows means the AddIn is 32-bit and therefore when querying the HKLM registry, the nodes are under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node.

We also have a stand-alone .NET app that runs in the bitness of Windows. So it goes to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE in the registry.

The problem is we save the license key for these apps (they both use the same key) in the registry. I want to avoid writing the license key twice because I then have to worry about just one of the locations being updated. And it means I have to have the app in each mode update both registry locations.

Is there a better way to do this?